# Отложенная подгрузка данных из sessionStorage для зависимых select

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

```js
sessionAll();
function sessionAll(){
 $('[name *= "pdata_ch_"]').each(function () {
 // if (sessionStorage.getItem(this.name)) {
 //  this.value = sessionStorage.getItem(this.name);
  if (sessionStorage.getItem(this.name) && this.type != 'radio' && this.type != 'checkbox') {
   this.value = sessionStorage.getItem(this.name);
  }else if(sessionStorage.getItem(this.name) && (this.type == 'radio' || this.type == 'checkbox')){

    var ses_name = this.name;
    var ses_val = sessionStorage.getItem(this.name);
    $('[name="'+ ses_name +'"][value="'+ ses_val +'"]').attr('checked','checked');
  }

  switch (this.type) {
    case 'text':
     this.addEventListener("keyup", function() {
      sessionStorage.setItem(this.name, this.value);

      console.log("---- text ----");
     });
     break;
    case 'radio':
     this.addEventListener("change", function() {

      sessionStorage.setItem(this.name, this.value);
      console.log("---- radio ----");
      console.log(this.value);
     });
     break;
    case 'select-one':
     this.addEventListener("change", function() {
      sessionStorage.setItem(this.name, this.value);

      console.log("---- select-one ----");
      console.log(this.name +' = '+this.value);
     });
     break;
    case 'checkbox':
     this.addEventListener("click", function() {
      console.log(this.type);
      sessionStorage.setItem(this.name, this.value);

      console.log("---- checkbox ----");
      console.log(this.value);
     });
     break;
    default :
    this.addEventListener("keyup", function() {
     console.log(this.type);
      sessionStorage.setItem(this.name, this.value);

      console.log("---- default ----");
     });
     break;
    }
 });
}
//тут с горем пополам я вывожу значение для второго селекта, но оно просто селектится и ajax
//для третьего селекта уже не срабатывает
setTimeout(function(){
 $('[name *= "pdata_ch_adr___city"]').each(function () {
  if (sessionStorage.getItem(this.name)) {
   console.log(this.name +' -->' + sessionStorage.getItem(this.name));
   var city_sel = sessionStorage.getItem(this.name);
   console.log($('[name="'+ this.name +'"] > option').length);
   $('[name="'+ this.name +'"] > option[value="'+ city_sel +'"]').click();//attr("selected", true);
   $('[name="'+ this.name +'"] > option[value="'+ city_sel +'"]').attr("selected", true);
 //  this.value = sessionStorage.getItem(this.name);
  }
 });
 
}, 3000);
```

Подскажите, что можно сделать с данной проблемой:  Есть 3 зависимых селекта, при выборе 1-ого Ajax'ом подгружается второй, при выборе 2-ого -> 3-тий. Следовательно невозможно выбрать необходимые пункты из sessionStorage. Что можно сделать в данной ситуации?

Comment: Почему невозможно? Сделайте [пример кода](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), который демонстрировал бы проблему. Вместо ajax можно использовать setTimeout для имитации асинхронности

Comment: А в чем проблема выбрать их сразу после загрузки селектов?

Comment: @Darth, в плане функционала самих селектов - ничего поменять нельзя, т.к. это компонент Fabrik в Joomla. Эти три селекта для примера, есть где селект зависит от `radio` или `checkbox`. И чтоб отследить `setTimeout'ом` все три селекта, то это значит и очередной `setInterval` вешать, хотелось бы избежать лишних циклов, их и так много посредством jquery висит ((. И как их выбрать после загрузки, если он может выбрать автоматом только первый, а во втором и третьем пусто еще, чтоб выбрать третий, нужно сперва второй выбрать. Списки из БД подгружаются.

Comment: @Petr Chalov, проблема в том, что селекты не загружаются одновременно.

Comment: @medvedev не получится сделать так:

После загрузки определенного селекта вытаскивать информацию именно для него из sessionStorage?

Скиньте пример кода.

Comment: @Petr Chalov, код добавил. Пробовал .click(), но не срабатывает.

Answer (score 0):

Насколько я понял задачу, нужно что то вроде этого:

В песочнице работать не будет, из-за политики безопасности(нет доступа к sessionStorage и localStorage)

```js
(function (window, storage, document) {

    var form = document.querySelector('form'),
        loadedOneSelect = false,
        loadedTwoSelect = false;

    form.addEventListener('input', onInput, true);
    form.addEventListener('change', onInput, true);

    //Реагирует на события input и change полей
    function onInput(e) {
        var target = e.target,
            name = target.getAttribute('name');

        storage.setItem(target.name, target.value);

        switch (name) {

            case 'pdata_ch_adr___city':
                loadSelect('pdata_ch_adr___country', fillFieldsFromSessionStorage);
                break;

            case 'pdata_ch_adr___country':
                loadSelect('pdata_ch_adr___state', fillFieldsFromSessionStorage);
                break;


        }
    }

    //Заполняет все поля при загрузке страницы из sessionStorage
    function fillFieldsFromSessionStorage() {

        var fields = document.querySelector('form').querySelectorAll("[name]");

        for (var i = 0; i < fields.length; i++) {

            if (storage.getItem(fields[i].name)) {
                if (['radio', 'checkbox'].indexOf(fields[i].type) === -1) {
                    var val = storage.getItem(fields[i].name);
                    (typeof val !== 'undefined') && (fields[i].value = val);
                } else {
                    var ses_name = fields[i].name,
                        ses_val = storage.getItem(fields[i].name);

                    try {
                        document.querySelector('[name="' + ses_name + '"][value="' + ses_val + '"]').checked = true;
                    } catch (e) {

                    }

                }
            }
        }
    }


    var loaded = {};

    //Ajax Mock
    function loadSelect(name, cb) {

        if (loaded[name]) return;
        loaded[name] = true;

        setTimeout(function () {

            form.innerHTML += '<div><p>SELECT ' + Date.now() + '</p><select name="' + name + '">' +
                '<option>Пункт 1</option>' +
                '<option>Пункт 2</option>' +
                '</select></div>';
            cb();

        }, 2000);

    }

    fillFieldsFromSessionStorage();

})(window, window.sessionStorage, document);
```

```html
<form>
    <div>
        <p>SELECT #1</p>
        <select id="one" name="pdata_ch_adr___city">
            <option>1</option>
            <option>2</option>
        </select>
    </div>

    <input type="checkbox" name="pdata_ch_2" value="2">
    <input type="text" name="pdata_ch_33">
</form>
```

Comment: К сожалению не вариант. Циклы будут очень долго обрабатываться, но главное что вариант с формированием селектов через `innerHTML` вообще не подходит. Списки (`option`) внутри `select` формируются недоступным для редактирования скриптом. По этому и надеялся, что есть вариант с реализацией подобия `"click"`, который запустил бы ajax. За ответ большое спасибо!