# Пытаюсь сделать динамичные селекты но не работают, не знаю что не правильно сделал

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

```
    <script>
    function selectKat2(){
        var kat1 = $('select[name="kat1"]').val();
        if(!kat1){
                $('div[name="selectDataKat2"]').html('');
                $('div[name="selectDataKat3"]').html('');
                $('div[name="selectDataKat4"]').html('');
        }else{
                $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "ajax.php",
                        data: { action: 'showKat2ForInsert', kat1: kat1 },
                        cache: false,
                        success: function(responce){ $('div[name="selectDataKat2"]').html(responce); }
                });
        };
};

function selectKat3(){
        var Kat2 = $('select[name="kat2"]').val();
        $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "ajax.php",
                data: { action: 'showKat3ForInsert', kat2: kat2 },
                cache: false,
                success: function(responce){ $('div[name="selectDataKat3"]').html(responce); }
        });
};
function selectKat4(){
        var Kat3 = $('select[name="kat3"]').val();
        $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "ajax.php",
                data: { action: 'showKat4ForInsert', kat3: kat3 },
                cache: false,
                success: function(responce){ $('div[name="selectDataKat4"]').html(responce); }
        });
};





    </script>
<div id="ilanekle" class="ilanekle" <?php if( temizle($_GET['is'])=="openadd" ) { } else { echo "style='display:none'" ;} ?> >
<form action="panel_elanlar_add.html" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="cmxform" id="ilanForm" onsubmit="return validate(this);">
  <fieldset>


         <p>
                <dl>
                        <dt><label for="kat1">Elan Növü Seçin:</label></dt>
                        <dd> 
                        <select style="width:305px" name="kat1" onchange="javascript:selectKat2();"   >
                            <option value="" >Elan Növü</option> <?php
                            $sql="SELECT * from kat1_elan order by kat_ad asc";
                            $sorgu=mysql_query($sql);
                            while($sehircek=mysql_fetch_assoc($sorgu))
                            {?>
                            <option value="<?php echo $sehircek['id']; ?>"  <?php if($kat1==$sehircek['id']) { echo "selected='selected'"; } ?>>
                            <?php echo $sehircek['kat_ad']; ?></option><?php }?>
                                                   </select></dd>
                </dl>
            </p>

        <div name="selectDataKat2" style="float:left;"></div>
        <div name="selectDataKat3" style="float:left;"></div>
        <div name="selectDataKat4" style="float:left;"></div>



//File ajax.php

<?php

ini_set(default_charset,"UTF-8");
# include data base
require "../include/ayar.inc";

switch ($_POST['action']){

        case "showKat2ForInsert":
                echo '<select size="1" name="kat2" onchange="javascript:selectKat3();">';
                $rows = $DB->select('SELECT * FROM kat2_elan WHERE kat1=? ORDER BY kat2_name ASC', $_POST['kat1']);
                foreach ($rows as $numRow => $row) {
                        echo '<option value="'.$row['kat1'].'">'.$row['kat2_name'].'</option>';
                };
                echo '</select>';
                break;

        case "showKat3ForInsert":
                echo '<select size="1" name="kat3" onchange="javascript:selectKat4();">';
                $rows = $DB->select('SELECT * FROM kat3_elan WHERE kat2=? ORDER BY kat3_name ASC', $_POST['kat2']);
                foreach ($rows as $numRow => $row) {
                        echo '<option value="'.$row['id'].'">'.$row['kat3_name'].'</option>';
                };
                echo '</select>';
                break;

        case "showKat4ForInsert":
                echo '<select size="1" name="kat4">';
                $rows = $DB->select('SELECT * FROM kat4_elan WHERE kat3=? ORDER BY kat4_name ASC', $_POST['kat3']);
                foreach ($rows as $numRow => $row) {
                        echo '<option value="'.$row['id'].'">'.$row['kat4_name'].'</option>';
                };
                echo '</select>';
                break;

};

?>
```

Comment: Что означает "Работает не правильно?" Какие ошибки возникают? Что должно произойти по задумке, а чего не происходит?

Comment: При выборе 1 селекта вывести второй селект где ID первого селекта указан на втором, а при выборе второго должно вывести 3 где ид второго селекта а при выборе 3 селекта так же показать 4. а если нету у кого то селекта подкатегорий то чтобы не показывал  а так при выборе первого селекта нечего не выводит

Comment: Почитайте здесь - https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/691866/%D0%9E%D1%82%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B3%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B7%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D0%B8%D0%B7-sessionstorage-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BC%D1%8B%D1%85-select